# Exclude a class from maven dependency

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am using [org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/ext/spring3) for Injecting Spring Beans into Jersey JAX-RS resource class. Bean injection works fine except for this jar also contains [SpringWebApplicationInitializer](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringWebApplicationInitializer.html) class which directly interferes with my own Custom WebApplicationInitializer. For testing purpose, I forcibly removed [SpringWebApplicationInitializer](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringWebApplicationInitializer.html) from initializing in [SpringServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html) in Debug mode and my app runs fine.

I also tried maven-shade-plugin with following configuration

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringWebApplicationInitializer.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This plugins copies both jars and classes to WAR file. SO even though SpringWebApplicationInitializer.class was removed, original jar (which still contains SpringWebApplicationInitializer.class) was copied and SpringServletContainerInitializer is still picking up SpringWebApplicationInitializer class.

Comment: "Bean injection works fine expect" -> do you mean "Bean injection works fine **except**"?

Comment: "But all the jars are still copied in my app.war along with all the Class files except SpringWebApplicationInitializer.class ." What is the problem? You exclude this file and you "complain" that it's not in the jar.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, what I meant was even though the class was removed in uncompressed version original jar was still copied to the war file which contains that class so SpringServletContainerInitializer is still picking up that class.

Comment: No reason to apologize :) Just need to understand to problem correctly. How do you build your war file (can to add the corresponding pom.xml part to your question)? If you want to shade something in you war, you need to assembly the war using the shade plugin...

Comment: Here is my pom.xml : http://pastebin.com/XmwjKVCk

Comment: You need to tell maven, that is should use the shaded jar instead of the original one. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/attached-artifact.html Also consider https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#finalName (I did not try it or used it by myself before. Let me know if it works.)

Comment: I tried this as well but it didn't work. I guess maven-war-plugin is copying the jars and maven-shade-plugin only works with jar packaging

Comment: Maybe you can try maven-assembly-plugin.... https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/ to package you war.

Comment: Have a look at  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357991/2587435). I think the first work around might work for you. There is a link to a complete example also